# How Can I capture user mouse clicks logging in Linux?

Tags: python

I want to logging user events in Linux.
Like mouse clicks and keyboard clicks.
I know pyxhook may solve the problem but i can't find any API of pyxhook.

Comment: how about [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and `pynput.mouse.Listener` and `pynput.keyboard.Listener`.

Comment: if you can find documentation then open `source code` of this module and see what functions it has, what is in functions, etc. There can be even `docstring` with explanations in functions. You may also try `help(function_or_class_or_module)` to see `docstring` without opening source code. And try `dir(class)` to see list with all methods and atributes  in this `class`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pynput library for it.

This should work:

```
from pynput import mouse


def on_move(x, y):
    print(f'{x, y}')


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(f'{button} pressed at {x, y}')


def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print('Scrolled {0} at {1}'.format('down' if dy < 0 else 'up', (x, y)))


def mouse_listener():
    with mouse.Listener(
            on_move=on_move,
            on_click=on_click,
            on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
        listener.join()

    listener = mouse.Listener(
        on_move=on_move,
        on_click=on_click,
        on_scroll=on_scroll)
    listener.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mouse_listener()
```